# Remove no longer used sprites from memory in Cocos2d-html5

Tags: cocos2d-x, cocos2d-html5

Because I'm developing on mobile devices, I wanna to remove no longer used objects (sprites) from memory. Should be detachChild be enough to have it out of memory ?
What about the src references. How to remove/detach them from the dom ?